# checked in checkbox, gives both false and true

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is like this:

```
$('#stateList').on("click", "#stateSelection", function(e) {  
   console.log($(this).find("#statecheckbox").is(":checked"));
});
```

When I click on checkbox, I can see both false and true values in console. That means this click event gets called twice. How can I fix this? Please note that stateList and stateSelection doms are getting created on the fly when some user action happens.

Comment: Do you more than one checkboxes with same id

Comment: Change `click` to 'change'

Comment: It doesnt matter if click/change

Comment: @T.J.Crowder see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CDnsL/1/ it could happen if you have a label and a checkbox - click on the label

Comment: And `change` event fixes the problem in the fiddle above

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Ah, yes, the old label/checkbox issue... Nice one.

Comment: Create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org); you'll probably find the problem through doing so, and if you don't you have something nice and contained to share.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the solution could is to listen to the change event instead of click, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [said behavior is possible](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CDnsL/1/) if you have a checkbox and a label.

Instead of the click event it is safe to listen to the change event like

```
$('#stateList').on("change", "#statecheckbox", function (e) {
    console.log(this.checked);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CDnsL/2/)